# Difference between "always" and "all the time"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

Do *always* and *all the time* mean exactly the same thing in these sentences?

> Why are you **always** so busy?
>
> Why are you so busy **all the time**?

Answer (score 3):

Always itself means all the time. So, both of them are very much interchangeable in usage.

Answer (score 2):

They both mean that the person is very busy on many different occasions.

Comment: Do you mean there is no difference in meaning and they can be interchangeable in these sentences?

Answer (score 0):

Although in most cases they can be used interchangeably, like in the sentence you have mentioned, there are some cases where *always* is more appropriate e.g.

> Always be prepared.

*"Be prepared all the time"* does not sound as good, I think, because *always* denotes perpetuity or continuity while all the time means repeatedly on multiple occasions.
I cant think of an opposite case, where *always* cannot replace *all the time* so i guess *always* trumps *all the time*.

Answer (score -2):

"Always" is used when a person is regarding time and event conjunctly; "all the time" is used when regarding time only, without regard to the event taking place at that time.

Comment: Hello, user28173, and welcome to English Language & Usage. The distinction you suggest in this answer is interesting, but it isn't one I recall seeing before. Please consider adding a reference (preferably with an online link) to a reputable reference work that supports your contention about the difference between "always" and "all the time." Thanks!